# Securing NM wiring on the electrical panel back board - Multi-cable staple

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, nec

Would much appreciate your input on whether -

1. It's NEC 2017 approved to use the below (or similar) multi cable staple when securing NM cable within 12" of the service panel, by attaching the cable staple to the back board and putting the cables into the staple.  I.e.: Can I just use that staple before routing the cable to the joists above instead of the typical white plastic staples that can usually only do 1 to 2 12/2 cables?
   Id just cut off that little piece that usually goes around the 2x4 so it's flat against the back board, and use both the nail and the screw.
   If not, and there is no way to secure the cables within 12" above the panel, what else do folks use to the side of it to staple many cables to the back board?
2. Do the NM cables have to be within a conduit when coming out of the service panel, on their way to the staple, and out of the staple on their way up to the joists (about a foot above the panel backboard)?  I've been reading some and am all turned around on the whole conduit requirement.

[image]

Comment: If you are going to run the cable inside conduit, you would secure the _conduit_ to your backer board, you don't end the conduit run, put a nipple on it to protect the cabling, put a staple on the "bare" cable, then a nipple and enter another piece of conduit. Unless you've got hours and dollars to waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those multi cable clamps are listed so they can be used I have used the 2 slot 4 cable a few times without issues from inspectors, the only issue with more than 4 they may call it bundling but the listing info shows 8 so it should be ok.

You will need a clamp entering / leaving the service panel some are listed for 2 cables I don’t know of any listed for more than 2, I love the plastic “insider” brand clamps they snap in pull the cable in and are done no screws or locknuts to mess with.
If you are talking about exposed romex we usually put a nipple in to protect the cables to a height of 8’ coming out of a nipple you do need to clamp or staple the cable as it comes out not inside.  I think that hit your questions.

Comment: My understanding is that a "nipple" is basically a 8" piece of conduit (say sched 80 for NM) that is attached to the panel via a clamp/fitting (like this https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-in-Non-Metallic-Liquid-Tight-Push-On-Connector-NMLT10-1/202284604)

So that nipple can stand up from the panel up to 8" on its own without needing to be clamped/fastened to the backboard (or anything)? Is there a code section that I can reference when the inspector asks?

Comment: The inspector won’t ask for the code ref if clamped prior to the conduit nipple. a nipple less than 24” doesn’t require derate but still the max fill tables are used. If not in conduit the clamp is needed is the part I was talking about.

Comment: Would you be able to comment on my follow up with those stackable staples? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/207680/running-nm-and-bx-cables-stackable-staples-rim-joists-nec2017-2020