# NM cable routing to panel backboard / side of the service panel. Take 2. Any NEC 2017/2020 concerns?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, nec

Going off of my previous [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201283/stapling-nm-cable-to-panel-backboard-on-the-side-of-the-service-panel-any-nec-2), I wanted to get a confirmation the below is compliant with NEC2017/2020 for connecting NM cable to a  main panel.

I have used a length of 12/2 NM cable to show how I intend to run about 12 of them (using additional multi-cable red fasteners) to the sides of the panel.  The cable isn’t through the knockout, but there will be a proper panel clamp in the final installation.  The first red cable tie (the one at the very bottom) will be within less than 12” of it’s panel clamp attachment.

[image: This is the overall picture:]

This is how the joist attachment looks like (top screw missing as it's a mock-up):
[image: This is how the joist attachment looks like:]
This is how the joist and middle attachments look like (not sure if proximity to the heating pipe matters but it won't touch it):

[image: This is how the joist and middle clamp looks like:]

This is how the panel side attachment looks like:
[image: This is how the panel side attachment looks like:]

Panel side will be covered with removable plywood, which goes all the way up to the joists to comply with the “physical damage” portion of the code (it will be securely fastened, this is just for example purposes):

[image: Panel board]

Please me know if you see anything you believe may not be NEC2017/2020 compliant.
Much appreciated as always.

Comment: Feel free to put a hinge and a latch on that piece of plywood.  **But hold up.  Why are *all the other* cables armored?**  Whenever you see that sort of thing, immediately call your AHJ and ask if there are any local ordinances requiring that.

Comment: Much appreciate the comment, Harper! In my area there is no requirement for armored cables only, this is just legacy 1950s wiring that I didn't rewire within the house.  All new wires (60% or so) will be NM and are allowed to be such.  
Unfortunately a hinge/latch solution (which would be great!) is prohibited by that pipe on the top left, but that is a very good idea for anyone else doing something similar, much appreciate the tip!

Comment: Just wanted to make sure on that.  For the hinge I'd use a horizontal hinge, draw a line just below halfway up the panel, hinges on both sides, whole thing flips downward :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting.   
Just a quick aside - the fact that the cable twists from horizontal to vertical back to horizontal from the joist to when it enters the panel isn't a problem, is it?

Comment: not at all. There are no limits to bends on NM cable.

Comment: Any comments on my next question would be much appreciated! https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/207680/running-nm-and-bx-cables-stackable-staples-rim-joists-nec2017-2020